# webpack dev server proxy post requests to local .json file

Tags: javascript, webpack-dev-server

I have a new project in hand, so I don't have any server-side support, they are not ready yet.

I want to mock my http requests with local json files.

I have two requests on-going:

1. /entity/get  method is 'GET'
2. /entity/create  method is 'POST'

And I have two local json files

1. mock/entity/get.json
2. mock/entity/create.json

In my config file:

config/index.js:

proxyTable: {

```
'/entity':{

    target: 'http://localhost:8080/mock/',

    pathRewrite(path) {

        return url.parse(path).pathname + '.json';

    }

}
```

}

build/dev-server.js

app.use('/mock', express.static('mock'));

Results:

1. /entity/get, I get what I want.
2. /entity/create, 404

My question:

1. Why cannot I get create.json responsed by the express server?
2. In webpack1.0  I had same question, but I handled the question by turning all post request to get request, the side effect is, I lost all request params during the post-to-get transition. I can live with it but in webpack 2.0 I even don't kown how to config like that.

Answer (score 2):

Question 2 soloved:

config/index.js:

```
proxyTable: {

'/entity':{

    target: 'http://localhost:8080/mock/',

    pathRewrite(path, option) {

        option.method = 'GET';

        return url.parse(path).pathname + '.json';

    }

}
```